# put some text on jvectormap

Tags: javascript, web, jvectormap

I'm using the jvectormap plugin and I would like to know if there is a way to put some text directly on the map, like the country's names for example ?

thanks !

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19123531/1324929